# I want to create multiple directories using shell script without using loops using one line command but I am not getting the desired results

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am writing the following shell script for generating multiple directories by providing arguments.
This is my shell script "createDirectories1.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"

mkdir $1{$2..$3}
#command mkdir $1{$2..$3}
```

And I am running the above script using following command

**bash createDirectories1.sh week 1 5**

And my expected output is
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHLJI.png)

[output which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHcmc.png)

[This is how my terminal looks when giving commands to execute the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5awiT.png)

I am not sure when I am running this command **mkdir week{1..5}** it works fine but when i run the same using shell script its not working

please help and let me know what modification is needed in my shell script ??

Comment: This syntax `{1..3}` ain't support variables, just real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

bash ranges work with literals, not variables, so you need some way to `eval` `{$2..$3}`; the problem with `eval`ing a string is that you have to ensure that it won't bite you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -a dirs="( $(printf '%q{%q..%q}' "$1" "$2" "$3") )"

mkdir "${dirs[@]}"
```

Comment: This is neat, even if technically not one line.

Comment: @PaulHodges look up neat in the dictionary. eval is neat. this is not neat. this is verbose, convoluted, and overly cautious i.e. nerdy. albeit safe.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Would you prefer `printf -v glob '%q{%q..%q}' "$1" "$2" "$3"; eval mkdir "$glob"` ?

Comment: no. your answer is perfect the way it is. no need to sprinkle eval on top of it.

Comment: you could *golf* it (and satisfy the oneliner requirement):  `eval mkdir $(printf '%q{%q..%q}' "$1" "$2" "$3")`, but I think you know that.

Comment: For those interested in *how* this works: see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573179/declare-command-and-shell-expansion) for a discussion. For @Jaroslav, please read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311737/lets-hold-language-in-comments-to-the-same-standard-as-posts) and curb the sarcasm, it isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `eval` command. The eval command first evaluates the argument and then runs the command stored in the argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"

eval mkdir $1{$2..$3}
```

Comment: Consider he execution: `createDirectories1.sh 1 ";echo $RANDOM;" 3` - any command passed in correctly this way runs. ***Don't*** try `createDirectories1.sh 1 ";rm -fr ~/*;" 3` or `createDirectories1.sh  ":(){ :|:& };:;"` ... if you use `eval`, make sure you [never pass raw user input to eval](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-safe-use-eval).

Comment: This is the sane and appropriate solution for the given scenario, everyone else is smoking something.

Comment: Not everyone owns the system, is the sole user, or is naive enough to disregard security when they don't know someone else's situation. I know I won't be using FortRabbit now...

Comment: Exiting this discussion now. Those who are interested can do the research for themselves.

Comment: The author of the competing answer failed to mention that you can make your solution more secure like this: `eval mkdir ${1//;}{${2//;}..${3//;}}` - just strip all the semicolons. Or test the input (must be number):  `function isnum { [[ $1 =~ ^-*[0-9]+$ ]] && return 0 || return 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need.

```
mkdir week_{1..5}
```

Let you know this answer :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/731721/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-directories-at-once-with-mkdir

Comment: But it doesn't work with variables.  I'm sure he doesn't want to hard-code the numbers into the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop:

```
for ((i=$2; i<=$3; i++)); { mkdir "$1$i"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your premise is flawed.

> I want to create multiple directories using shell script without using loops using one line command

Why? You could make a loop with on one line if that were somehow important, but it really shouldn't be. If it's an assignment, be aware that your instructor is probably expecting an `eval` and (if they are any good) planning to screw you with it.

But there are still ways, if you allow for the fact that there's always a loop under the hood somewhere. For example -

```
 seq "$2" "$3" | xargs -I@ mkdir "$1@"
```

That's "one line", though it could just as well be written as

```
 seq "$2" "$3" | 
   xargs -I@ mkdir $1@
```

You could make it

```
xargs -I@ mkdir $1@ < <( seq "$2" "$3")
```

It's still executing a subshell, but it's "one line", and `xargs` & `seq` aren't *exactly* loops. This also doesn't use `eval`, so it's a lot safer.

Now the whole script is

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$@"                              
prefix="$1"; shift                              # shift prefix off $@
xargs -I@ mkdir "${prefix}@" < <( seq -w "$@" ) # add leading zeros
```

And if I run it as
./tst 1 ";echo rm -fr ~;" 3

then it successfully *fails* without executing any malicious code.

```
$: ./tst 1 ";echo rm -fr ~;" 3
1
;echo rm -fr ~;
3
seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘;echo rm -fr ~;’
Try 'seq --help' for more information.
```

but with valid args it's good.

```
$: ./tst foo 9 12
foo
9
12

$: ls -ld ./foo*
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Jan  5 11:39 ./foo09
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Jan  5 11:39 ./foo10
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Jan  5 11:39 ./foo11
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Jan  5 11:39 ./foo12
```

Comment: Wow. Such insight! Definitely worthy of a ***Sr. Technologist***. When you're done looking up neat, check out this one: brevity. Sorry man, this is not a good answer.

Comment: Which answer was yours?